# Flask error: werkzeug.routing.BuildError when connecting to web service

Tags: python, flask

For educational purposes, we're building a very simple Flask app. While it runs smoothly locally, it no longer does when I copy the code to my virtual private server.

The route is defined as follows:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def sign_up():
...
```

This is the function that uses autocomplete:

```py
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = f"SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title"
        query = cursor.execute(sql)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        # from flask import jsonify
        results = [data[i]['title'] for i in range(len(data))]

    return render_template("autocomplete.html", results=results)
```

`autocomplete.html` is located in the templates folder, which sits next to the Python program file.

And the web service is started like this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I can start the web service successfully, but when I connect using the URL, it returns a 500 error, and the server console shows:

```
[2020-05-28 16:19:47,099] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "app.py", line 94, in sign_up
    return render_template("autocomplete.html", results=results)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 140, in render_template
    ctx.app,
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/root/recommender/app-flask/templates/autocomplete.html", line 10, in top-level template code
    $.getJSON("{{url_for('autocomplete')}}",{
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 370, in url_for
    return appctx.app.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2216, in handle_url_build_error
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 358, in url_for
    endpoint, values, method=method, force_external=external
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 2179, in build
    raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'autocomplete'. Did you mean 'static' instead?
```

I assume this is because of a change in the URL, but I don't know how to solve this.

Can anyone help?

Comment: what url are you connecting to? Was there an endpoint autocomplete before and now you have deleted it? I would also try to restart the application with just ```app.run(debug=True)```

Comment: Where is this endpoint "autocomplete" mentioned in your error message? I do not see that in your code posted

Comment: Later in the code, we have:

```python
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        sql = f"SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%%'"
        query = cursor.execute(sql)
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        from flask import jsonify
        results = [data[i]['title'] for i in range(len(data))]

    return render_template("autocomplete.html", results=results)
```

Comment: @mrgou Add the information you added here into your original post please. It is easier to read code there as that allows code formatting and syntax highlighting

Comment: Ah, yes, duh! :-D

Comment: @mrgou Another question, the stack trace the is giving the above error message usually specifies somewhere where the error message is occurring. Could you please upload your stack trace as well

Comment: Full trace added

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON("{{url_for('autocomplete')}}",{`
=> your code wrong at this line, read more about [url_for](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for) in flask.

It's need to render route like: `<blueprint_name>.<function_name>` If use `app` as route use can skip `blueprint_name` => Ex: `.sign_up`
[sample](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#url-building)

Comment: Not sure I understand. It works locally and only fails when running on the server. Can you clarify what I need to change?

Comment: Let's try with: `$.getJSON("{{url_for('.sign_up')}}",{`

Comment: Same error: `werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'signup'. Did you mean 'sign_up' instead?`

Comment: Have you ever try with `$.getJSON("{{url_for('sign_up')}}",{`?